# Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null Java Netbeans Graphics2D

Tags: java, netbeans

i have problem with detecting my image it allways says that its location its null idk what to do.
I need the image to be called.
I have tryed most things and still cant figure it out.
i have tryed in the resources package, in another package, with the full path, and still nothing if.

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Class.java to edit this template
 */
package game.objeto;

import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

/**
 *
 * @author sousa
 */
public class Player {
    
    public Player(){
       
        this.image=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("resources/plane.png")).getImage();
        this.image_speed=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("resources/plane_speed.png")).getImage();
    }
    
    
    public static final double PLAYER_SIZE=64;
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private float angle=0f;
    private final Image image;
    private final Image image_speed;
    
    public void changeAngle(float angle){
        if(angle<0){
            angle=359;
            
        }else if(angle>359){
            angle=0;
        }
        this.angle=angle;
    }
    
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2){
        AffineTransform oldTransform = g2.getTransform();
        g2.translate(x, y);
        g2.drawImage(image, 0,0,null);
        
        
        g2.setTransform(oldTransform);
    }
    
    public double getX(){
        return x;
    }
    
    public double getY(){
        return y;
    }
    
    public float getAngle(){
        return angle;
    }
}
```

and error is

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:232)
    at game.objeto.Player.<init>(Player.java:22)
    at game.componentes.PanelGame.initObjectGame(PanelGame.java:74)
    at game.componentes.PanelGame.start(PanelGame.java:69)
    at game.main.Main$1.windowOpened(Main.java:35)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Window.java:2082)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(JFrame.java:298)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2044)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4991)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4823)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thx in advance

Comment: You probably want `getResource("/plane.png")` and `getResource("/plane_speed.png")`.  The argument must be relative to the packaged application, not relative to your project’s root.

Answer (score 2):

I recently went through the same issue. The problem is that for some reason, Netbeans requires you to create the "resources" folder, and within that folder, create the packages that will contain your images or resources. So, the first step to solve this problem would be to create the folder.

To do this, go to the "Files" section in the navigation bar, then expand the folders until you reach the "main" folder. There, you need to create the "resources" folder and paste your images there. You can simply add them by dragging and dropping the images into the folder.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Once you've done this, go back to the "Projects" section, where a folder called "Other Sources" will have been added. In this folder, you have to create a Java package with the name you want to give to that resource section. In my example, I named it "images."

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

After creating the "images" package, I added the images to it. You can simply add them by dragging and dropping the images into the package.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finally, now you can add the images you want to your jLabels, just make sure they are being added from the package you just created in "Other Resources."

I hope my answer has helped you. If you need any clarification, feel free to leave your comments.

Comment: This works for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I often get that error when trying to display an image on a JLabel.
The solution is to edit the Netbeans IDE generated code by removing the usage of `getClass().getResource()` method inside the `new javax.swing.ImageIcon` constructor.
The new code should look something like this:

```
    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("full or relative path to resource"));
```

In the case of Netbeans IDE you may have to go that JLabel then click on the JLabel.
On the jLabel properties select "icon" property. Then on the pop-up menu select "set jLabel1's property using: Custom Code
There will be a JTextField below and on that text field is where you append the code similar to what i shared above.
This approach was tried on Netbeans 16 with JDK 19 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using Maven

maven has a very bad problem with image rendering

do the following in your pom.xml file:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        </resource>
     </resources>
</build>
```

And I believe it will work perfectly

Comment: Not sure this will solve anything.

Comment: You trying make this way?

Answer (score 0):

```
URL resource =UsuarioForm.class.getResource("/com/lrt/agendaonline/user.png");
   perfil.setIcon(new ImageIcon(resource));
```

Comment: Please [edit] to put a transalation of that as an explanation into the answer itself. All posts need to be English and only providing code without an explanation is rarely perceived as an helpful answer on StackOverflow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Posts on Stack Overflow have to be in English](/help/non-english-questions). Please [edit] the post to translate it. If you feel more comfortable writing in Portuguese, feel free to visit our sister site [pt.so].

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project and then click on build. After that, you can run the file

I decided like this

Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This is because you make a non static reference using `.getClass()` to fetch a resource URL. You must use a static reference using `Player.class` instead. Furthermore, if /`resources` has been defined as a source folder in your project, you don't need to prepend the image path with that source folder path.

Try this:

```
public Player(){
    this.image = (new ImageIcon(Player.class.getResource("/plane.png")).getImage());
    this.image_speed = (new ImageIcon(Player.class.getResource("/plane_speed.png")).getImage());
}
```

Comment: If the stack trace contains `java.awt.Window`, I very much doubt it’s a web application.

Comment: You're right, I didn't see it